# Magento Admin backend NOT saving

Tags: magento

There are 2 attributes, Visibility and Tax Class, which no matter what does NOT save.

I've disabled cache, cleared cache, flushed cache. Deleted the contents in var/cache, but to no avail.

Has anyone run into this before, or can anyone point me in the right direction to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to save a product. The steps I would take are:

1) Check if your using a flat table structure.

2) Check your index's to see if they require a rebuild. System -> index management

3) Put magento into developer mode. SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE in your apache config.

4) Enable more PHP error reporting in php.ini ( Set error reporting to ALL.)

Have you installed any modules that might be effecting those settings ?